# How to sort a file in unix both alphabetically and numerically on different fields?

Tags: unix, sorting

Please don't think this is a repeat of the "Sorting alphanumeric data in unix" question... I looked at the other answers, and think my case is a bit different!

I have data like this:

```
A    192
D    112
D    188
C    091
A    281
B    919
```

...And I want to sort first column 1 (alphabetically), and then by column 2 (numerically). I tried using:

```
sort -n -k1,2
```

...But this gave me correctly sorted for the first field, but then the wrong sorting for the second field (1000,1002,1003,10,1 ... instead of 1,10,1000,1002,1003).

Can someone please suggest how to sort these two columns the way I'd like?

Comment: sort -k4,4n -k1,1 ????

Comment: I should mention that both columns can have between 1 and 50 chars to their string, and each line is different

Comment: `sort -k1 -nk3 file` should work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try using like this:-

```
sort -k1,1 -k4,4n
```

> - -n : Makes the program sort according to numerical value
> - -k opts: Sort data / fields using the given column number. For example, the option -k 2 made the program sort using the second
>     column of data. The option -k 3,3n -k 4,4n sorts each column. First
>     it will sort 3rd column and then 4th column.

Comment: Thanks for the command/answer! I tried this, and I see where you are going with this, but it doesn't work for my data, because the values in each column aren't a fixed character length. In my example I used character length 1 for column1, and 3 for column2, but in reality the character length is between 1 and 50, depending on the line. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I reversed the command to sort on column 2 first, then column 1:  `sort -k1,1 -k4,4n` and this seems to work. Can you please explain how the command works? I am unfamiliar with `-k4,4n`

Comment: @jake9115:- Updated my answer with the explanation of both. Hope that helps :) P.S. Dont forget to accept this as an answer if that really helped you ;)

Comment: It is puzzling that the answer sorts on column 4 when there only seem to be two columns in the data. Nevertheless, the basic answer (use `-k` to specify which columns to sort on, and how to sort them) is valid.

Comment: This method works great for sorting revision tags. For example: `git tag | sort -t. -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3`

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
sort -t "," -k1,1 -k2n,2 file
```